# Detect red rectangles (or squares) using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm newbie with OpenCv and I need to detect red rectangles in an image.

I have found a lot of examples of how to detect red circles with OpenCV, like this [one](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/detect-red-circles-image-using-opencv/). But,

How can I detect red rectangles with OpenCV and C++?

I want to do the same that the above tutorial, that recognizes this circles:

[image]

But, instead of circles, I want to recognize rectangles and squares. I want to start with the easiest part, next I will change the lighting conditions.

Comment: In what lighting cinditions? Against what backgrounds?

Comment: I have found this example in OpenCV samples dir: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to this, I would suggest you the easiest method for detection of shape objects, like rectangles. First, you will apply thresholding to segment image (you may use `Canny()`), then extract contours using `findContours()` of rectangle and lastly use `approxPolyDP()` - It approximates a contour shape to another shape with less number of vertices depending upon the precision we specify. It is an implementation of Douglas-Peucker algorithm.

```
cv::Mat src = ...;
cv::Mat gray = ...;
cv::Mat bw;
cv::Canny(gray, bw, 800, 850, 5, true); // Modify values for your use-case

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> countours;
cv::findContours(bw.clone(), countours, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

std::vector<cv::Point> approx;
cv::Mat dst = src.clone();

for(int i = 0; i < countours.size(); i++)
{
    cv::approxPolyDP(Mat(countours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(countours[i]), true) * 0.01, true);


    if (approx.size() == 4)
    {
        double maxCosine = 0;

        for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++)
        {
            double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j % 4], approx[j - 2], approx[j - 1]));
            maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
        }

        if (maxCosine < 1.2)
        {
            cv::line(dst, approx.at(0), approx.at(1), cvScalar(0,0,255), 4);
            cv::line(dst, approx.at(1), approx.at(2), cvScalar(0,0,255), 4);
            cv::line(dst, approx.at(2), approx.at(3), cvScalar(0,0,255), 4);
            cv::line(dst, approx.at(3), approx.at(0), cvScalar(0,0,255), 4);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this method detect **all** quadrilaterals (rhombuses, trapezoids, parallelograms, etc.), not only rectangles? Was the bounding box `r` left in your code accidentally or did you intend to use it?

Comment: Well yes, you are right, i forgot to calculate and compare angles. I will update my answer, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You could also check to see if the lengths of the diagonals are equal (within some tolerance).

Comment: You can try to perform OpenCVs "rotated rectangle" which returns 4 points and calculate the area of the rotated rectangle. Then use OpenCVs "contourArea" which returns the area of the contour. If the two are the same or in small tolerance then it should be a rectangle

Comment: I only want to detect red rectangles. Does this method do it? Where in code do it?